# Getting an id without using an input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this table, and I get the id of each row by using:

```
  <td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
```

And then I take this id with:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

What I really want is to get the ID for each row without showing it in a `<td><input>`

How can I do that?

Comment: you mean `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="value">`? or you can iterate with something like this: name="id_<?php echo $i++;?>

Comment: you're going to have to elaborate on your question.

Comment: what is wrong with you @Fred-ii- ? I really didnt understand you

Comment: Oh, so now you're answering. You see that 2nd comment? It means something. We have comment #1 that is the same as the answer given and hasn't provided you with a solution where you commented under the answer given what you really want to achieve. Something that should have been included in your question from the get-go. Your question will end up in next-to-endless comments. Now that guy deleted his answer and for a few reasons I'm sure.

Comment: where do you want to use this $id?

i have a suggestion you can directly store id in $id like: 

$id=$rows['id'];

Comment: Ok @Fred-ii- sorry I get it.

Comment: @JaswinderKaur, yes I will try it

Comment: Felipe Umpierre's answer was correct all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<input type="hidden">` however, in that case, the `id` will be in your html. It will not be visible for users, however, programmers will be able to find the ids. Instead, I suggest to not even put those ids into the html.

Instead, find a criteria which makes each row public. For instance, if the triple of (name, address, phone) is guaranteed to be unique, then you do not need to put the ids into the html `table`, but query your database for tuples which fulfill the unique criteria. If the triple of (name, address, phone) is not guaranteed to be unique, then you need to find another unique criteria. In the worst-case scenario, you will need to implement a token-system.